# Why does Angular 11 and Electron produce window with no content

Tags: angular, electron

I have followed the tutorials to create and Angular/Electron desktop app.  When I run ng Serve, i see the content on the browser screen.  When I build and run electron-build, I get a desktop window with no content. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myProj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && npm run electron" 
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "electron": "^11.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win;

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600, 
    height: 670,
    icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/assets/logo.png`
  })

  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`)

  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {

if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})   

app.on('activate', function () {
  // macOS specific close process
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RsInvPro</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html:

```
<H2> Content is here!!!</H2>
```

Comment: I don't see electron as a dependency in your package.json. Have you installed it?

Comment: It was there in the project.... don't know what happened, but it is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be its white screen issue. Make sure the below points are covered.

**main.js**

Point 1: Make sure the path is correct. Is it dist/index.html or dist/{YourAppName}/index.html?

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/{YourAppName}/index.html`)
```

Point 2: Use SplashScreen, so if there is any delay on content you can find the problem

```
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/{YourAppName}/SplashScreen.html`);
setTimeout(function () {
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/{YourAppName}/index.html`);
}, 1000);
```

Point 3: Once the app ready, then show to the world

```
win.once('ready-to-show', function () {
        win.show();
})
```

**Note:** Ignore {YourAppName} if your project inside the dist folder directly

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  Stupid of me not to think of that...

Answer (score 0):

you should update your angular app's config

example

> src/index.html

```
<base href="#">
```

> src/app/app-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```